# How do I modify the contents of a cell, if the date in another cell is 7 days before todays date?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I have 1 Column with the date formatted as so "1/7/19", In the next column, I would like to check if the previous date is 7 days from Today's date. If True, I'd like to add an emoji into the second column.

I have the first column using conditional formatting which is coloring respective cells Red.

```
=IF(TODAY()-7<=Q3, "")

=CONCATENATE(R3, "", Q3)
```

I plan to concatenate these two columns into a third that shows " 1/7/19" if True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1<=TODAY(), A1>TODAY()-7), "☺ "&TEXT(A1, "M/d/yy"), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: let me know if you need array formula